# Best phone to test own developed android Application?

Tags: android

Which is the best phone to test own developed android Application??

Comment: As many different phones as you can get your hands on.

Comment: Samsung GALAXY S, 4 life! But this is a very subjective opinion

Comment: A fast PC which runs the Android Emulator. You can create as many different Emulators (different CPU, different Resolutions...) as you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTC Desire is a very good phone to carry with you, and for testing your Android applications too.

Answer (score 8):

```
if ( you.haveMoney() ) {
 // You should get at least one.
 you.buyDevice();

 // If you still have money, get as much devices as you can.
 while ( you.haveMoney() ) {
     you.buyDevice();
 }

} else {
 // You can always use the emulator.
 you.useEmulator();
}
```

PS: The only way I found to turn this question into a programming related :)

Answer (score 0):

Best phone to test is **Nexus one** or **Nexus s**

Answer (score 0):

If you can find out which is the phone that the majority of your users is likely to use, go for that. If you don't know, then see which is the highest selling phone. If there is a choice among a few different phones, go for the model which has other siblings models in it's family.